# How can I force the browser to open my urls in an existing tab rather than a new one?

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, tabs

In a WinForms application, I have a form in which I have a couple of link labels.
When the user clicks on any of the links I want to open a page in an EXISTING browser TAB that my own application has opened.
(Of course except for the first time that it should open a new tab)
My problem: 
Process.Start("My Url"); opens a new tab all the time. 
Is there any way that I can tell the browser to stop opening new tabs?

Thanks before.

Comment: I found this [link] (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43491/Opening-IE-Using-C-and-Firing-Events), Hope it helps

Comment: Did you ever managed to solve this as i have exactly same issue which i am struggling?

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion Unfortunately no I didn't find a way.

Answer (score 4):

That behaviour is defined on a per-browser basis, and is a user setting that you shouldn't attempt to meddle with. If you do require this level of control, have you considered hosting a browser control within your application instead?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. The 'new' and 'existing' tab problem is solved, BUT the destination site has some problems with the WebBrowser Control which is out of my control. (for example so many popup windows are used in the site, and I get so many errors when I try to navigate and work with the site). That's why I think WebBrowser is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the INternetexplorer you can work with `ShellWindows` 
Example and description: [Launch a URL in a tab in an existing IE window from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713206/launch-a-url-in-a-tab-in-an-existing-ie-window-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm talking about a new TAB, not a new WINDOW.