# Opening an Internet Explorer Windows with Exactly 3 Tabs in it

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, firefox, shdocvw

I'm working on a project with a coworker and we have been beating our heads over our desks trying to figure this one out.  Our requirements are to have a new Internet Explorer browser pop up with one webpage and then append two tabs to it.  We found a solution that works on my coworker's computer, but when we tried it on my computer and another coworker's computer, it would not work.  What we have so far:

```
using SHDocVw;

...

ShellWindows iExplorerInstances = new ShellWindows();    
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.reddit.com");
Thread.Sleep(5000);
string url = "http://www.google.com";
IEnumerator enumerator = iExplorerInstances.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
InternetExplorer iExplorer = (InternetExplorer)enumerator.Current;
iExplorer.Navigate(url, 0x800); //0x800 means new tab 
url = "http://www.banana.com";
enumerator = iExplorerInstances.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
iExplorer = (InternetExplorer)enumerator.Current;
iExplorer.Navigate(url, 0x800); //0x800 means new tab
```

Again, this works correctly on only his computer.  For me, when I try to run this code, it opens up the Internet Explorer browser correctly, but even though I'm using an InternetExplorer object, it opens up the tabs in Firefox.  I delved into the class and tried to print out anything useful I could find.  The name property in my InternetExplorer object was "Windows Explorer".  I read up more on what ShellWindows actually does and that makes sense, but it doesn't help me.  This seems to imply that it's opening up my default browser through the InternetExplorer object instead of Internet Explorer.  I also had different results from my coworker who has Chrome as a default browser.  I switched my default browser to Chrome to see if that was the issue, but then the two extra tabs opened in Chrome.  All I really need is to open an Internet Explorer browser with 3 tabs each with their own URL.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you allowed to open it on a file?  If so, you could try opening it on a file which in turn opens multiple pages from the same instance, which should open multiple tabs.  I'm not sure how reliable this behavior is...

Comment: The actual code is going to be embedded into a tray application that pops these windows when a certain condition is met.  It will be installed on several computers, and I'm not certain that using a file is going to be the best choice of implementation.

Comment: Those are some strange requirements which seem to be counter to a good user experience. Can you not combine your datasources and display them in a single page?

Comment: To be more specific, this application is going to be run on an automated machine that is performing particular actions that interact with customers.  These pages are supposed to pop up three webpages (one has actual customer data, two more are Google searches based on data set in DDE) so that anyone who checks in on the machine can view all of this data without having to dig for it.  The requirements are pretty strange, but that's what they're paying us for.

Comment: then why not just make IE the default browser on that specific machine?

Comment: Maybe programmatically put javascript:window.open('','_blank'); in the address bar a couple of times to create the new tabs?

Comment: In an ideal world, that would work.  This is going out to a customer that wants it to just install and run on their machines, and if they also don't ahve IE as their default browser, they aren't going to enjoy Internet Explorer popping up with half of their information and Firefox/Chrome having the two tabs.

Comment: I figured out why this wasn't working.  I'm opening a window AS my code is continuing to run and the code is processing before the iexplore.exe actually opens, which is why it's not finding the iexplore.exe with my ShellWindows object.  By putting in a 1 second wait, the original code works just fine.  I had a similar issue before where calling Process.Start(url) three times would open three tabs if iexplore.exe was already open, but would only open the final tab if it wasn't opened yet.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this guy has the solution you are looking for:

[Launch a URL in a tab in an existing IE window from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713206/launch-a-url-in-a-tab-in-an-existing-ie-window-from-c-sharp)