# Process.Start opens multiple instances

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, process, visual-c#-express-2010

I have the following code:

`Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + "\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", "http:\\\\someurl.com");`

It runs fine, but opens two instances of IE (Needless to say, I'm expecting one). Is there something obvious I'm missing here, or is it a more detailed issue? I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express if that matters, and .NET 4 Client Profile.

Comment: If IE is not your default browser you can use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713206/launch-a-url-in-a-tab-in-an-existing-ie-window-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the exe path to IExplore and just let Process start the link, in my experience this should open in a new Tab not window

Example:

```
Process.start("http:\\\\someurl.com");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is to open a webapp that requires IE.

Comment: is IE not your default browser?

Comment: Nope, and I'd prefer not to assume that it is on the user's end either.