# How to open new Tab in an existing IE window

Tags: internet-explorer, nsis

Only for IE8+, need help with NSIS coding to open new Tab in an existing IE window.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, IE opens tabs however it wants (which usually means "Same window." The problem you're probably hitting is that your installer doesn't specify `RequestExecutionLevel user` which means that Windows automatically elevates it to Admin. When you launch URLs or programs from an elevated program, they launch in an elevated child process. IE can't mixed non-elevated tabs and elevated tabs in a single frame, so you always get a new window. (Also, keep in mind that running the browser elevated turns off its sandbox, so it's extremely dangerous).

Comment: The installer prompts for admin rights, but current IE instance runs under user. I found some code here on C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713206/launch-a-url-in-a-tab-in-an-existing-ie-window-from-c-sharp

Comment: I wouldn't expect the ShellWindows approach doesn't work, due to the crossing of integrity levels. Did you try it?

Comment: I created similar on VBS and being executed from CMD with admin privil.  it opens new tab in the existing IE10 window running under user.